# Updating mongo db document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am looking to update mongodb document using `findOneAndUpdate` not sure of it right now.

My Document example:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5860f0ec197e7a05812fbddd"),
    "username" : "krapali",
    "last_updated" : ISODate("2016-12-26T10:29:00.557Z"),
     "max" : 6,
    "min" : 6,
     "data" : [{
                    "dataAdded" : {
                            "min" : 6,
                            "max" : 6,
                    },
                    "dataAdded" : {
                            "min" : 5,
                            "max" : 7,
                    }

    }],
    "data_count" : 2
```

If you observe above sample document, you will see it array of object.

Whenever I try to update my document I will be having 3 fields with me `username, max and min`. depending on username I need to add/push into data array a new element as well as I need to update min and max field and increase data count by one each new update.

Can some will help me how to do it?

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far so we know which part is not working for you ?

Comment: will you update username as well ? or is it used to find the records?

Comment: It will find username

Comment: Please check answer below and vote if worked for you.

Comment: It all can we done in single operation, see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is very simple. first, make a call to db to get the document which you want to update and create a variable `update` here whatever updates need to be done. And just use `findOneAndUpdate`.

```
// input to function username, min and max
modal.findOne({username: username}, function(err, data){
    var minmax = {dataAdded: {min: min, max:max}};
    var update = {
        $push: {
            data: minmax
        }
    };
    update.$set = {
        data_count: data.data.length + 1,
        max: max,
        min: min
    };

    modal.findOneAndUpdate({username: username}, update, {new: true}, function(err. updatedDoc){
        // do whatever you want with updated document
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to use findOneAndUpdate method

```
modal.findOneAndUpdate({username: username},{
  $push: {
    data: {
      dataAdded: {
        min: minValue,
        max: maxValue
      }
    }
  },
  $set: {
    min: minValue,
    max: maxValue
  },
  $inc: {
    data_count: 1
  }
},{
upsert: false,
new: true
}, function( err, doc ) {
});;
```